# Debian : Unable to start Firefox : libXcomposite.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: debian, firefox

I am installing Firefox version 36.0 on Debian 9.3

Initially I install the following 3 packages:

```
- xvfb
- libdbus-glib-1-2
- imagemagick
```

I then downloaded the deb file `firefox-mozilla-build_36.0-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb`

And I install it then.

Once completed, I try to run Firefox but it gives me the ERROR:

```
vagrant@packer-debian-9:~$ firefox
XPCOMGlueLoad error for file /opt/firefox/libxul.so:
libXcomposite.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Couldn't load XPCOM.
```

I cant seem to find what the issue here is. Is there a specal library I need to  install ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That deb package `firefox-mozilla-build_36.0-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb` you are trying to use is for Ubuntu and not Debian; it is also an oldish version of Firefox from 3 years ago. As such, it has dependencies missing.

To install Firefox in Debian Stretch do:

```
apt-get install firefox-esr
```

> Package: firefox-esr (52.9.0esr-1~deb9u1)
>
> Mozilla Firefox web browser - Extended Support Release (ESR)
>
> Firefox ESR is a powerful, extensible web browser with support for
>   modern web application technologies.

PS Be aware were from and how you get new packages. The repository where you found your `deb` file is clearly Ubuntu-oriented.